# How to resize the scrolling output height in jupyterlab notebook?

Tags: html, css, jupyter-notebook, jupyter, jupyter-lab

Is there a way to resize the scrolling output height in jupyterlab notebooks ?

*potential solutions but require HTML/CSS knowledge*

1. I found this snippet from this question [resize ipython notebook output window](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18770504/resize-ipython-notebook-output-window) useful but it wont work on jupyterlab

   ```
   from IPython.core.display import display, HTML
   display(HTML("<style>div.output_scroll { height: 44em; }</style>"))
   ```
2. I found this CSS snippet here [Jupyterlab active scroll bars for long results](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48816081/jupyterlab-active-scroll-bars-for-long-results) which can be included using `stylus`. It works to make the scrolling output smaller but for some reason doesn't work to make it larger than the default height

   ```
   .jp-OutputArea-child {
    max-height: 15em;
   }
   ```

**Note** the scrolling output am talking about can be achieved by `right clicking` + `enable scrolling for output`

*Main issue:*

when am working with jupyterlab notebooks I sometimes have very long outputs, and so I would `right clicking` + `enable scrolling for output`. Then the output is folded however I would like to resize that scrolling output (see figure below)

[image: Make the output cell bigger in terms of height]

I am using jupyterlab version **2.2.9**

Note, i am aware of the following and they don't work for me:

- sidecar extension
- `create new view for output` functionality

Comment: Could you provide an example of dummy long output that causes this issue and your JupyterLab version?

Comment: @krassowski just did that.

Answer (score 2):

The first snippet you posted can be modified to the following to work with JupyterLab (tested with version 3.1.18):

```py
from IPython.display import display, HTML
display(HTML("<style>.jp-CodeCell.jp-mod-outputsScrolled .jp-Cell-outputArea { max-height: 44em; }</style>"))
```

The value of 44em can be adjusted as you desire to increase the visible area more or less.